# Adjusting my data with linear regressors doesn't improve the model

Tags: predictive-models, linear-model

I'm working with a relatively simple dataset: I have data for the same participants, but from two different sources "A" and "B".

The data looks like this:

Participants     Source A     Source B

```
  1           0,5678       0,6789
  2           0,5472       0,6098
  .              .            .
  .              .            .
  .              .            .
```

What I'm aiming for is to prove that a conversion of the data from one source to another is feasible. After some descriptives, it was obvious that my data was following a linear model like this...

prediction <- lm(sourceB ~ sourceA, data=data)

After using summary(prediction), the following parameters appeared:

slope = 0,7869

int = 0,0076

R^2 = 0,802

And I extracted the intercept and the slope in order to apply it to sourceA, becoming sourceA_converted. I don't know if this is correct, but I believe that sourceA_converted and sourceB data are now comparable. In order to do the aforementioned I...

1) Created new columns for the intercepts and slopes

data$slope <- 0,7869

data$int <- 0,0076

2) Created a function to apply the conversion to my data:

conv <- function(a, b,c) {
  new_source <- (((a*b)+c))
  return(new_source)
}

3) Applied this function to my data in the following way:

data%>%

mutate(A_to_B = conv(sourceA, slope, int))

In that way, I obtain a new column with the conversion done for every participant.

Finally, I investigate how this converted data behaves with sourceB:

conversion <- lm(sourceB~A_to_B, data= data)

The result is the following:

slope = 1,007

int = 2·10^-7

R^2 = 0,802

As you can see, the R^2 remains the same, when it should be closer to 1 than before. I don't really know why this is happening. Does anybody know? Is there some step where I messed up? Maybe the whole conversion using mutate is messing the data somehow (though I don't know how is that possible...)

Anyway, thank you in advance for any contribution!

Mario

Comment: Why not leverage a 'train-test' approach as in k-fold cross-validation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics) )? By partitioning your data as recommended by these approaches, at least one additional metric can be added to the ones you're already evaluating...out-of-sample predictive accuracy.

Comment: Why did you expect the R^2 to change? All you have done is produce the predicted values of y given x. These will have the same R^2 with y as the model that generated the predicted values.

Comment: Additionally, the only reason your slope and intercept were not 1 and 0 in the second model is that you rounded them to 4 digits in your equation. Compare the output of the "predict" function to your converted data. You will see that they are the same except for rounding errors.